# How to offset objects in relation to the curve using geometry nodes?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, instances

I have a simple geometry node that places spheres along a curve. I don't know much about geo nodes, but I'd like to know how to modify it so that I can set the offset of the sphere in relation to the curve (move the spheres but along the normals of the curve)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've added picture showing curve above. Here's the link to the blend file
https://tiny.pl/wx36z

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, unfortunately, you cannot use the normals of the curve as direction, because they point in a completely different direction than the surface of the shield.

You would therefore have to use the normals of the faces directly, and you can solve this as follows:

Use `Object Info` to process the shield.

Then add the node `Transfer Attribute` with the setting "Nearest Face Interpolated" and use the node `Normal` as attribute.

This will give you the normals of the nearest faces of your shield, starting from the positions of the instantiated spheres.

You then only need to scale this vector according to your wishes and transfer it to your instances with `Translate Instances`.

[image]

*Note: I have hidden the irrelevant options and socket here in this example, so that the space requirement is not so large. You would have to show them if you need them.*

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for explanation!

Comment: @KonranT You are welcome!

Comment: This is the correct answer, but uses the 'flat' normals of the nearest face. If you desire to use the 'smooth' normal you can place an 'Interpolate Domain' node between the position field and the Attribute Transfer node so it will interpolate the normal of the nearest vertices.

Comment: @BertVdB Correct. However, the `Interpolate Domain` node is only available in version 3.3 (beta).

Comment: @quellenform ah I've gotten so used to using the latest daily builds I didn't know that is such a recent node. Good catch.