# How to bend the mesh?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, surface-deform

I would like to deform/bend the mesh (picture 1) to achieve results similar to picture 2.

I would like to know your opinions or recipes on how to do it right. I have tried simple deforming and meshing but no luck :-(

Maybe I am doing something wrong. There are nodes, curves (I haven't tried).

This is what I have:

[image: pic1]

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: pic2]

Comment: hello, there's also the Cast modifier, or the proportional Editing, but it also depends on your topology, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried proportional editing at the end, but for some reason it was curving the mesh to one side. After a lot of experimentation and moving vertex by vertex I found the best place (centre of mass?). Unfortunately there was another problem with the back (some artifacts were appearing there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Geometry Nodes* solution:

[image]

It depends very much on your underlying mesh how the result looks like, but I tried to rebuild the mesh and create an example with it:

[image]

Here I simply rotate the positions around a certain axis, which I get via the cross product of the up vector and the position.

The length of the position vector I map to a certain value, with which you can influence the strength and direction of the bending.

Since I know your request more exactly, I get the vertex group and create a curve from it.

From this curve I create the decoration on the shield, but you already know that from your other question ([How to offset objects in relation to the curve using geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/272769/145249)).

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Thank you! You're amazing :D

Comment: One more question. If I'd like to add my own sphere (object) instead of adding "eco sphere" to the "instance of points". How should I do it properly?

Comment: @KonranT For this you can use the node [Object Info](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/object_info.html) instead.